# Why does my wp_enqueue_script() only insert the script for logged in users

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

I've got a really simple enqueue in my `functions.php` file. The weird thing is that it only actually inserts the script if I'm logged in. I've tried wiping out everything else in the `functions.php` but it doesn't change anything. I'm not even sure what to try next. Any ideas?

```
function enqueue_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-script.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_script' );
```

Comment: Is the script not being added to the page? Or is it not working? It's an important distinction.

Comment: Is there any caching plugin on your site? (Or maybe your server uses some cache?)

Comment: @JacobPeattie the script is not being added to the page.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż only the standard WPEngines cache which doesn't feel like a likely culprit for something like this

Comment: Does your theme’s header.php file have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in it?

Comment: @JacobPeattie it's a child of the Astra theme and header.php has not been overwritten so yes.

Comment: Is there already a script enqueued called ‘my-script’?  That’s the last thing I can think of. Otherwise there’s nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I've tried changing the name but it hasn't made any difference.